# VB Realtime Datagridview Search VB 2008

Tags: vb.net, vba, datagridview

The way I displayed my `datagridview` was just by dragging from the data source.

Most of the codes I found in the internet manually creates a connection but in my situation there is already a connection of sort. So I do not know where to start. What I do know is that I displayed the data of the database just by dragging the datagridview from the data source panel. And I also have the following things active: dataset, bindingsource, tableadapter and tableadaptermanager.

What I'm trying to do is to create a real time search in the datagridview. As soon as the user inputs a character on the search text box. The datagridview is being filtered automatically.

Any suggestions or links to sources will really be appreciated.

Comment: what's this question about? vb.net or vba? what kind of application? what have you tried? please read the article [ask] in order to help us to help you.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Drag And Drop then you must have a DataSet designer.

1. Go to Dataset Designer -> Go to your DataTable in designer
2. Now add a query to that datatable with where clause. Where clause will accept value from search textbox. To do that, create query like :

> select * from  where = @ColumnName

i. If you are using SQL then follow above Query.
   ii. If Access then just use **?** after =

3. Save query with proper Name and save dataset.
4. Now create event for search Textbox ( TextChanged event will do better )
5. Use fill method of that datatable to fill the datagridView on texhchanged event. e.g

> DataGridViewName.QueryName(Me.DataSetName, TextBoxName.Text)